# Upload images to image gallery using HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in which I load all the images from a folder which I am doing with the below code.  I also have a text box, in which I can enter any image URL (ex: http://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_640x430/public/happy-first-birthday.png) and a button below when I click that new image should show on top of the existing div which has other images.

I tried with the commented code, but no luck. I think the page is getting refreshed and the image is disappearing.

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            for (var i = 0; i <= data[i].photo_url.length; i++) {
                //alert(data[i].name);
                $("#loadIMG").append($("<div class='col-xs-6 divImg' <p > <img  ALIGN='top' src=" + data[i].photo_url + "></img> " + data[i].name + "</p>"));
            }

//            $("button").click(function () {
//                alert($('#url').val());
//                var imgURL = $('#url').val();
//                $("#loadIMG").append($("<div class='divImg' <p> <img  ALIGN='top' src=" + imgURL + "></img></p>"));
//                //$("#loadIMG").html("<img src='" + imgURL + "' alt='description' />");
//            });

        });
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-content">
        <form>
            <label class="label">
                Photo URL</label>
            <input class="input" name="photo_url" id="url" />
        </div>
        <button id="btnCreate">`enter code here`
            Create</button>`enter code here`
        <!--<input type="button" id="btnCreate" value="Create" class="button" />-->
        <hr />
        </form>
        <div  class="row" id="loadIMG">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Question:
If i put the some google URL which has image, in the input text and button click should show the image below along with the other images. How can i achieve that? I tried appending to the div with the commented code, but the image doesn't show. 
[Screen Reference]

Comment: What do you want from us? What do you did til now? Where is the problem and what do you expect from us? To do your work? Please add a Question and explain what's your problem is. Also it seems you are new here, please use the "edit" button to do so, don't use the answer function.

Comment: Well for starters you're not even closing the first DIV bracket `<div class='col-xs-6 divImg' ` <-- wheres the `>` AND you're not closing the div at the end `</div>` this is going to create such a web of mess in the DOM

Comment: @CagatayUlubay his attempts are in the question body, you need to actually read the question before typing nonsense

Comment: @vtz Adding a text and assume than everybody knows the question is the worst behaviour. If someone missunderstands the question, he will give a complete different answer than the creator wanted to. *Always* post a question so everybody knows what you want. Also after j08691 edited it, there is still NO question, so before getting upset about typing nonsense, deliver me a question. There is no question. A question is marked with a question mark `?`. Also with common-sense there is still NO question. There are just a bunch of facts. "I do this and that and this happens". Cool, whats the problem?

Comment: Also the title is the worst. Imagine you have the same problem and want to google for it.. are your first google phrases `HTML, CSS and Javascript` or your actual problem?

Comment: @CagatayUlubay the title is the worst yes :) you r 100% correct, but the other part... i think you need to relax a little bit

Comment: edited as per the comments.

Comment: Where are you guys? After editing the questions no replies?

Comment: @vtz I spend a lot of years in coding forums and I know when something is wrong. I had many moments where I googled something and came to stackoverflow and loved this page, because the quality is very high here. But there was many threads that lacked in quality and was closed.. so I didn't got an answer and this made me sad, because if the quality was a little bit better, the thread wouldn't be closed. But it's ok for now, a question was edited in the main part. We can stop the discussion :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form:

```
 $("button").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      /** the rest of your button's on-click code **/
 });
```

Comment: Thanks umopepisdn. I have did adding the image up on Create. But i need to append to existing div which has few more images. Added a screen shot for reference.

Comment: I can't see the screenshot. Aren't your existing div the `#loadIMG`? So appending should add the url image into the existing images.

Answer (score 0):

If the page refresh just put " event.preventDefault(); ". http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
 $("button").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($('#url').val());
               var imgURL = $('#url').val();
               $("#loadIMG").append($("<div class='divImg' <p> <img  ALIGN='top' src=" + imgURL + "></img></p>"));
              //$("#loadIMG").html("<img src='" + imgURL + "' alt='description' />");
           });
```

Comment: How do i add this new image to the existing images of div?